# How to keep only one image in SlidesJS without auto play?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using SlidesJS in one of my project, it's dynamic banner with autoplay, sometimes this will have only one image, at that time i want to stop the auto play

Comment: show us some code that you have tried.

Comment: http://slidesjs.com, this is th plugin i had used

Comment: This is the normal flow  <div id="slides">  <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="">  <img src="img/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="">  <img src="img/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="">  <img src="img/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="">  <a href="javascript:viod(0);" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>  <a href="javascript:viod(0);" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of images that contains your banner if contains less than 2 images then doesn't set SlidesJs properties.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#NameOfYourDivContainningBannerImages').children().length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    ($('#NameOfYourDivContainningBannerImages').slidesjs({
         ....
 });
```